# Select only one checkbox for product pairings x 3

Tags: php, jquery

I am displaying products from my Product database in a table, with a checkbox to select the product that is desired.

Each product has 3 variants or price point options, entered in the database as seperate items for each price point variation.

```
Code    category Description            Points                Choose your Points
1001-B  Logo    artwork supplied    Basic                 4.00 points
1001-S  Logo    artwork supplied    Standard          6.00 points
1001-P  Logo    artwork supplied    Premium               12.00 points
1002-B  Logo    re-draw to vector   Basic                 6.00 points
1002-S  Logo    re-draw to vector   Standard          8.00 points
1002-P  Logo    re-draw to vector   Premium              14.00 points
```

There are 3 price point variations for every product: Basic, Standard and Premium. Each "Product" has the same Product Code. So as above Product: 1001-B is the Basic, 1001-S is the standard and 1001-P is the premium.

So the customer chooses which Price point option they want by selecting the checkbox next to each item.

I am wanting to only allow them to select one price point / product for each product pairing (ie only one of the 3 price points).

So basically to get the checkbox to work like a radio button. I cannot use a radio button because I am using the same name for all of the items in my checkbox array: name="id[]"

```
echo '<input type="checkbox" name="id[]" value="' . $id . '" /></td>';
```

How can I achieve this?

I know I can do the following:

```
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[1][]" />
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[2][]" />
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[2][]" />
<input type="checkbox" class="radio" value="1" name="fooby[2][]" />


$("input:checkbox").click(function() {
    if ($(this).attr("checked") === true) {
        var group = "input:checkbox[name='" + $(this).attr("name") + "']";
        $(group).attr("checked", false);
        $(this).attr("checked", true);
    } else {
        $(this).attr("checked", false);
    }
});
```

But this relies on the fact that name="fooby[1][] name="fooby[2][] etc changes. I cannot do that in my case.

Any ideas?

I have already got the cart aspect of this after the page is submitted resolved so I don't want to make fundamental changes to the checkbox format I have.

Comment: Any chance of adding unique "rel" or "class" attribute for each group?

Comment: OK, got it. Works a treat. How cross browser compatible is it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's add class attribute to each group and handle with it:

```
<input type="checkbox" value="1B" name="id[]" class="group1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="1S" name="id[]" class="group1" />
<input type="checkbox" value="1P" name="id[]" class="group1" />
<p>&nbsp;</p>
<input type="checkbox" value="2B" name="id[]" class="group2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="2S" name="id[]" class="group2" />
<input type="checkbox" value="2P" name="id[]" class="group2" />

$("input:checkbox").click(function() {

    $('input:checkbox[class="' + $(this).attr('class') + '"]').prop('checked', false);
    $(this).prop('checked', true);

});
```

Comment: I see, looks very workable. I am no JQuery expert, what do I do with the "....do whatever with the group and this element...."? Sorry :)

Comment: OK, got it. Works a treat. How cross browser compatible is it?

Answer (score 2):

WHenever you have repeating modules within a page it's easy to isolate instances by traversing up to a main parent of the instance and searching within that parent only.

HTML

```
<div class="product">
   <div class="name"/>
  <div class="description/>
  <div class="choices">
       <input type="checkbox"/>
   </div>   
</div>
```

JS:

```
$('.product input:checkbox').change(function(){
   if(this.checked){
      $(this).closest('.choices').find('input:checkbox').not(this).prop('checked',false); 
   }
});
```

No knowledge of any properties of the checkboxes is required using this generic traverse pattern. If checkbozes aren't wrapped in labels can shorten to:

```
 $(this).siblings().prop('checked',false);
```

Comment: Looks like a nicer solution if group of checkboxes can be wraped into other element.

Comment: So with this option I would have to add a <div class="choices"> for each group of 3 (pairing)? This would give me the ability then to only select one of the 3 in the group?

Comment: can traverse to the main `product` element also without needing to have the `choices` element. Compartmentalizing different components, or groups of components within each `module` is very helpful though for layout and manipulation

Comment: There are many, many ways to do that. The basic idea is "grouping the inputs any possible way". It can be done by attributes, by wrapping to other element, even by just counting they index etc. Just choose the best to fit your layout.